# Puppet - mysql module not pulling "my.cnf" from fileserver

Tags: mysql, puppet

Trying to deploy mySQL puppet.
Using "Puppetlabs-MySQL" module.

My puppetmaster'd pp has

```
node 'jira.oracle' { class {'mysql::server':} }

class mysql::server {

  package { "mysql-server": ensure => installed }
  package { "mysql": ensure => installed }

  service { "mysqld":
    enable => true,
    ensure => running,
    require => Package["mysql-server"],
  }

  file { "/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf":
    owner => "mysql", group => "mysql",
    source => "puppet:///fs/my.cnf",
    notify => Service["mysqld"],
    require => Package["mysql-server"],
  }

  file { "/etc/my.cnf":
    require => File["/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf"],
    ensure => "/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf",
  }

  exec { "set-mysql-password":
    unless => "mysqladmin -uroot -p$mysql_password status",
    path => ["/bin", "/usr/bin"],
    command => "mysqladmin -uroot password $mysql_password",
    require => Service["mysqld"],
  }
}
```

and fileserver.conf has

```
# MOUNT POINTS
[fs]
    path  /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules
    allow *
```

But agent is still not pulling "my.cnf" from puppet master with errors:

```
"Error: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/File[/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///fs/my.cnf
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/File[/etc/my.cnf]: Dependency File[/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/File[/etc/my.cnf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/Service[mysqld]: Dependency File[/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/Service[mysqld]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/Exec[set-mysql-password]: Dependency File[/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/Exec[set-mysql-password]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.51 seconds"
```

Comment: I tried to accept the proposed review, couldn't figure out how. Why do I have a downvote? Is the error message too verbose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the mount point, say /etc/storage, for what you are going to use on pp. Put three /// in front of the mount point you define.

(fileserver.conf)

```
[fs]
    path /etc/storage/  
    allow *
```

(nodes.pp)

```
source => "puppet:///fs/my.cnf",
```